# How to pass arguments through factories requests

Tags: javascript, angularjs, factory, mean.io

I use the [RIOT GAMES API](https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods). And I use factories for my API calls. First of all I request the summonerName and then I use this name to get the id of this summonerName.

I tried with:

```
 $scope.summonerId = $scope.summoner.id;
```

And then access to this $scope but it doesn't work:

I recived this error with and **undefined** where I should recive the summonerId. (21694436) this is my summonerID :

```
https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/undefined/summary?season=SEASON2016&api_key=foo-bar-foo-bar-foo-bar
```

I have got the following javascript code:

```
'use strict';

angular.module('mean.system').controller('SummonerController', ['$scope', '$http','APIAcces', '$stateParams',
  function($scope, $http, APIAcces, $stateParams) {        

  $scope.summonerName = $stateParams.summonerName;

  APIAcces.getSummonerByName($scope.summonerName).then(

        function successCallback(response) {

           $scope.summoner = response.data[$scope.summonerName.toLowerCase()];                
           $scope.summonerId = $scope.summoner.id;

           console.log($scope.summonerId); //returns id successfuly
           console.log(response);
        }, function errorCallback(error) {

           console.log(error);
           console.log(response);
        },  

//if I do.. APIAcces.getSummonerSummary('21694436').then( // it works!
        APIAcces.getSummonerSummary($scope.summonerId).then(

            function successCallback(response) {

              $scope.summoner2 = response.data[$scope.summonerId]; 
              console.log(response);

            },function errorCallback(error) {
              console.log(error);
              console.log(response);
            }
        ) //End APIAcces.getSummonerSummary

  ); //End APIAcces.getSummonerByName

  }
]);
```

I pass the argument **summonerId** and this factory it doesn't recognize it.
[I use this method:](https://developer.riotgames.com/api/methods#!/1080/3726)

```
angular.module('mean.system').factory('APIAcces',['$http','API_KEY',
        function($http,API_KEY){
            return {
                getSummonerByName:function(summonerName){
                    return     $http.get('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.4/summoner/by-name/'+summonerName+'?api_key='+API_KEY.KEY);
                },
                getSummonerSummary:function(summonerId){
                    return     $http.get('https://euw.api.pvp.net/api/lol/euw/v1.3/stats/by-summoner/'+summonerId+'/summary?season=SEASON2016&api_key='+API_KEY.KEY);
                },
            }
        }]).value('API_KEY',{
            KEY: 'foo-bar-foo-bar-foo-bar'
    });
```

I don't know, maybe it is an order of factories or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your code, it's a typical async callback problem. you may have to first understand javascript callback and async architecture by reading somewhere else.

The reason is because

```
APIAcces.getSummonerSummary()
```

is being called when

```
APIAcces.getSummonerByName()
```

has not finished fetching, so the summonerId is undefined, it's just an async programming's nature.

so to correct this, you have chain the call together  like this:

```
    APIAcces.getSummonerByName($scope.summonerName).then(
    function(response){
        var summonerId; //extract the id from response
        APIAcces.getSummonerSummary(summonerId).then(
            function(response){
              //response should contain the summary
            },
            function(error){
                //error of getting by id
            }
        );
    },function(error){
    //error of getting by name
});
```

Comment: *ajax's nature of being async

Comment: it's not necessary for ajax,  you can even built you own "async" function like timeout()

Comment: I know, more that I mean it's not the javascript itself that is async in this case, but the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems. Trimming the contents of your functions shows the first problem:

```
APIAcces.getSummonerByName($scope.summonerName).then(

    function successCallback(response) {
        // success
    },
    function errorCallback(error) {
        // failure
    },  
    APIAcces.getSummonerSummary($scope.summonerId).then(
        function successCallback(response) {
            // inner success
        },
        function errorCallback(error) {
            // outer success
        }
    )
);
```

The third parameter is the finally parameter but you are not passing in a function. You should do this:

```
APIAcces.getSummonerByName($scope.summonerName).then(

    function successCallback(response) {
        // success
    },
    function errorCallback(error) {
        // failure
    },
    function finallyCallback() {
        APIAcces.getSummonerSummary($scope.summonerId).then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                // inner success
            },
            function errorCallback(error) {
                // inner failure
            }
        )
    }
);
```

---

The second problem is that you probably don't want this in the finally block anyway. If your request fails, you will not have an appropriate summoner id to work with. It should be moved to the success block:

```
APIAcces.getSummonerByName($scope.summonerName).then(

    function successCallback(response) {
        // success

        APIAcces.getSummonerSummary($scope.summonerId).then(
            function successCallback(response) {
                // inner success
            },
            function errorCallback(error) {
                // inner failure
            }
        )
    },
    function errorCallback(error) {
        // failure
    }
);
```